# Parse - Many to One Query

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parse-platform, nosql

I have a query that gets latest posts by users. Each post has an "Owner" field that has the "ObjectId" of the account that created it. I do this because I want to also display the username of the person who created the post - which is found in the User table.

I looked at the Parse documentation for Queries and came up with this (modeled after one of their examples):

```
    var query = PFQuery(className:"Post")
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt");

    var innerQuery = PFQuery(className: "User")
    innerQuery.whereKey("objectId", matchesQuery: query)
```

Then I run the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`. I don't think I'm getting the information from the User table to get the name of the person who posted the post.

I looked at the object that contains the information for the post but I don't see the information for the user in that object. What am I doing wrong?

Here are screenshots of the headers of my two tables:

POST:

[image: Owner should match ObjectId in next table]

USER:

[image: The ObjectId here should match Owner in Previous table]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem as that you refer to the user table in the query as "PFQuery(className: "User")". But if you use the built in user table, it's name is actually "_User". So use that, or even simplier, use:

```
var innerQuery = PFUser.query()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    var class = PFQuery(className:"Post")
    var finduser:PFQuery = PFUser.query()
    finduser.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: class.objectForKey("owner").objectId)
    finduser.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
                (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!)->Void in
                if (error == nil){
                    if let userObjects = objects {
                        let UserResult = (userObjects as NSArray).lastObject as? PFUser
                        if let user = UserResult {
                           println(user.username)
                            }
                    }
               }
     }
```

Comment: Hmmm... I'm guessing you didn't meant to name that very first variable as "class"? Either way, I tried this and it didn't seem to work. I'm going to give it another try. Perhaps I missed something? Is this from something you have working @user528432?

Comment: i just named it class or whatever you want. this works for me , what error are you getting?

Comment: Where you have finduser.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: class.objectForKey("owner").objectId), I get the following error: --> PFQuery does not have a member named 'objectForKey'.